# Is this $2020$ holiday formula correct? $\pi\left( \dfrac{\left( \pi!\right)!-\lceil \pi \rceil \pi! }{{\pi}^{\sqrt \pi}-\pi!}\right)=2020$

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, gamma-function, solution-verification, pi

I found the following formula in another math group:

$$\large\color{blue}{\pi\left( \dfrac{\left( \pi!\right)!-\lceil \pi \rceil \pi!  }{{\pi}^{\sqrt \pi}-\pi!}\right)=2020}$$

It actually looks very "elegant". But, then I used Wolfram because I was in doubt.. [The result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi*%28%28%28pi%20%21%29%21%20-ceiling%28pi%29%20pi%21%29%2F%28pi%5E%28sqrt%20pi%29-%20pi%21%29%29) shows that this formula is wrong.

I wrote these steps:

$${\qquad \quad \color{red}{\pi\left( \dfrac{\left( \pi!\right)!-\lceil \pi \rceil \pi!  }{{\pi}^{\sqrt \pi}-\pi!}\right)=\color{blue}{\dfrac {\pi \Gamma(1 + \Gamma(1 + \pi))-4 \pi \Gamma(1 + \pi))}{{\pi}^{\sqrt \pi} - \Gamma(1 + \pi)}}\color{red}{\approx55221,71}}\color{blue}{\neq2020}}$$

> My questions are:
>
> - I wonder if there is a small typo in the formula?
> - Or is the formula far from accurate in any case?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The outer $\pi$ is the [prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).

Comment: Or, $\pi(17577.6)=2020$

Comment: In Mathematica, `PrimePi[17577.61614280863]=2020`

Comment: With a [Wolfram Alpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PrimePi%5B%28%28pi+%21%29%21+-ceiling%28pi%29+pi%21%29%2F%28pi%5E%28sqrt+pi%29-+pi%21%29%5D)

Comment: I get $\pi! \approx 7.18808$  and $(\pi!)! \approx 7380.5556$   You also need $\pi^{\sqrt \pi} \approx 7.6063$

Comment: @Henry so we have "two different pi" in the same formula? Do I understand correct?

Comment: @Elementary I see what happened, you multiplied by the initial $\pi$ so you got about 55,221. But no, this one has a different meaning.

Comment: @WillJagy I mean  pi in parentheses and pi not in parentheses are used in different meanings.?

Comment: @Elementary in this case, yes, different meanings are intended. From a table of primes: 2018 17551
2019 17569
2020 17573
2021 17579
2022 17581    https://oeis.org/A000040/b000040.txt

Comment: The Y2K bug of 20 years ago has returned as a nomenclature bug.  I remember my quantum mechanics textbook where they were doing some calculations for electrons and they had to use the same variable $m$ for both mass and one of the quantum numbers.  :-S

Comment: From Wolfram MathWorld: "The notation pi(n) for the prime counting function is slightly unfortunate because it has nothing whatsoever to do with the constant pi=3.1415.... This notation was introduced by number theorist Edmund Landau in 1909 and has now become standard. In the words of Derbyshire (2004, p. 38), "I am sorry about this; it is not my fault. You'll just have to put up with it."